# Sharepoint on premise 2019 - pass query string parameter to page title

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I am looking for help with displaying the query string parameter on the page,

column: project leads

URL with Query string:
`https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/IAS_Projects/SitePages/by%20User.aspx?projectleads=joe%20dirt`

I would like to display this as the title for the above URL.
Project - Joe Dirt

I was getting close using this example, but it shows "joe%20dirt".

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var vars = [], hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}

  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {    
    $('span#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').each(function () {      
         $(this).empty();
         $(this).append("Project - " + vars[‘project leads']);
    });
}, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `decodeURIComponent()` OR `decodeURI()` function to remove encoded characters from URL like:

```
decodeURIComponent(vars['project leads'])
```

OR

```
decodeURI(vars['project leads'])
```

---

**Update from comments**:

Try this code:

```
$('span#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').each(function () {      
    $(this).empty();
    var projectLead = decodeURIComponent(vars['project leads']);
    $(this).append("Project - " + projectLead);
});
```

Comment: how would i add it?  i tried it like this, but didnt work..  

$(this).append("Projects - " + decodeURIComponent(vars['project leads']);

Comment: It should have worked for you if you are getting `vars['project leads']` part correctly. check updated answer.

Comment: thank you for your help Ganesh (and very fast) , i will try that, i dont get sharepoint sometimes, my original script was working before and now i cant even get that to work, it just stopped working on page.

Comment: your a genious Ganesh, that worked like a charm, i have been looking for that answer for days... thank you SOO much